# Can my Windows 7 computer read a Windows 10 HDD as external storage?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, file-transfer

I'm creating a new computer and intend to go back to Windows 7. My current computer is Windows 10.

Is there a solution so that I can access files from my old computer on my new one by attaching it as an external hard drive? I only need to access it a few times in case there are files on my old HDD I want to access.

I am open to any suggestions aside from this, such as cloud storage, or converting my existing computer to Windows 7 so the hard drive can be compatible.

However, I cannot simply use the old computer as file storage as the new one will be using some of its parts.

Comment: Yes;  Windows will respect the permissions of the files, which means if you want access to the files, you will have to taken ownership of them.

Comment: yes, if the drive data is not encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Both Windows 7 and 10 use the same file system.  This means either computer can read the other's hard drive.  Assuming this computer is from this decade, it will have a SATA hard disk.  Just get one of these [SATA to USB adapters](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_11?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=sata%20to%20usb&sprefix=sata%20to%20usb%2Caps%2C164&crid=FTH5IOIPKLD6), and you can connect the Windows 10 hard drive to your Windows 7 machine.